# How to resolve socket programming error?

Tags: c++, sockets

I i am implemeting a machine problem and i am stuck with an error, and i dunt know what's the problem , i want to send command line arguments into sendto() but it gives me error please provide me with a solution.I know the problem lies within the arguments of sendto() ... Below is the client program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char*argv[])

{

char msg[100];
int i=0;

char * adress;
char * subject;
char * name;

adress=argv[i+1];
subject=argv[i+2];
name=argv[i+3];

if(argc>9){
cout << "Just provide three arguments in commandline,please. " << endl;
}



int conn_sock,n,err;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
conn_sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

if(conn_sock ==-1)
{
perror("\n\nError in making socket and error is");

cout<<"Error No:\t\n"<<errno;
exit(0);
}


server_addr.sin_family= AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_port = 1234;
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");


int p=sizeof(server_addr);
//const void*  a =( const void*(strlen(adress)));
n=sendto(conn_sock,msg,0,(sockaddr*)&server_addr,p);

exit(0);
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: i resolved the error thanks :)

Comment: So delete the question. It is worthless without the error and the solution. Next time include the actual error message in your question.

Comment: i have another problem i have to send address,message and text file to server so one sendto() and rcvfrm() will do that or i need three function calls for each ??

Comment: So ask a new question, and delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `sendto` as follows:

```
n = sendto( conn_sock, msg, 0, (sockaddr*)&server_addr, p );
```

You missed the `flags` argument for the call above. See [sendto documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto).

```
ssize_t sendto(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
               const struct sockaddr *dest_addr, socklen_t addrlen);
```

Comment: okay resolved it thanks also i have another problem i have to send address,message and text file to server so one sendto() and rcvfrm() will do that or i need three function calls for each ??